# hide a div after certain percent of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a div which have two CTA buttons.I'm going to hide this div after reaching 90% of the page or reaching to my #footer div. The reason i'm doing this is to prevent it from interfering with footer.

I had found some codes but it will hide the div after 800px scroll not based on percentage .

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*hide this div after reaching 90% of the page:*

You need to get 90% with `Math.round($(document).height() * 90 / 100)`

```js
var height = Math.round($(document).height() * 90 / 100);

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > height) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>
```

*or reaching to my #footer div*

You need to use `offset().top` for getting element offset from window:

```js
var height = Math.round($('#footer').offset().top);

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > height) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>
<div style="height:1000px;"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Great Pedram. Worked for me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: But @pedram u had did the opposite. I want the  bottomMenu hide when reaches to footer.

Comment: @MohammadGhonchesefidi simply change `>` with `<` ;)

Comment: @pedram I was trying these snippets . yes it works for me and great thanks for your time dude.

Comment: @pedram Worked for me

Comment: @MohammadGhonchesefidi Your welcome, so accept this answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have converted it in Percentage. Update `PER` value to update config.

```js
//PER is Percentage value
var PER = 90;
var yInPixel, totalHeight;

//If page if with dynamic height change totalHeight and yInPixel after Resize Event
$(document).ready(function() {
  totalHeight = $(this).height();
  yInPixel = totalHeight * (PER / 100) - window.innerHeight;
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y > yInPixel) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>
```

Comment: This is very bad for performance. You will redo the calculation on each scroll which is useless. It's better to put this logic outside.

Comment: what if page is having dynamic height and changing it on some event.

Comment: `if page is having dynamic height` : but it's not the case here. So this is not suitable here (am not against your solution if course !) Or you may consider adding more comments to your answer to explain it so that you answer is better than the other ;)